# How to make parent background opaque but keep child element non opaque?

Tags: android

[image]

Hi guys I am new to Android .I want to make the layout given in the image.
I want to achieve the effect inside the red box.How can I make the background opaque while its keep its child opaque?
I tried this as,
The part inside the red box as `RelativeLayout`, which has a `TextView` (value as Contact details) I gave android:alpha=0.3 for relative layout,but the problem is,it makes the `TextView` also opaque (which is logical)
I just want some thoughts to move in that direction.

Answer (score 2):

Create a color resource with an alpha component of 0.3 and set it as the background of the `RelativeLayout`

In the colors.xml

```
<color name="opaque_black">#4c000000</color>
```

In the layout of the View

```
<RelativeLayout
    ...
    android:background="@color/opaque_black"
    ...>
```